# Step in the prove that the covariant basis is a covariant tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

From this step in [this video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/TC98KfiGAOk?t=2085):

$$\frac{\partial \vec R(Z')}{\partial Z^{i'}}\overset{?}=\frac{\partial \vec R(Z(Z'))}{\partial Z^{i'}}$$

where $\vec R$ is a position vector differentiated with respect to the different coordinates $Z^{i'}$ in the prime coordinate system $Z'.$

I think the denominator on the RHS should be in the un-prime coordinate system:

$$\frac{\partial \vec R(Z')}{\partial Z^{i'}}\overset{?}=\frac{\partial \vec R(Z(Z'))}{\partial Z^{i}}$$

Is this correct? Was there a slight mistake on the presentation?

---

He explains it in his book step-by-step right after equation $(6,10),$ and would be the answer to the question from another user that has been linked to this one:

$${\bf Z_{i'}}=\frac{\partial \vec R(Z')}{\partial Z^{i'}}$$

> The function $\vec R(Z')$ gives the position vector $\vec R$ as a function of the coordinates $Z^{i'}.$ The following is the critical step from which the ultimate relationship is derived. The function $\vec R(Z')$ can also be constructed by substituting $Z^i(Z^{'})$ — the expression for the unprimed coordinates in terms of the primed coordinates— into $\vec R(Z)$ that is the function that gives the position vector $\vec R$ as a function of the unprimed coordinates $Z^i$:

$$\vec R(Z')=\vec R(Z(Z'))$$

Comment: Ahahaha I think that every single person who saw his lecture had this same doubt. I myself recall having this :P

Comment: I found that part somewhat okay, I felt that he abandoned the idea of 'geometric calculations' after second or third lecture which made me lose a lot of the interest. You can check Tristan Needham's book where everything is fully geometric. At the end I think so pretty much equivalent theory is developed.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer with a concrete example in the first comment, lemme know if it helped.